# S3 and encrypted SQS integration issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, amazon-kms

I have an SQS event set for S3 bucket.When a file with name xyz.txt is uploaded in S3, SQS event is called and then this SQS calls an lambda.

This workflow is working fine.

Now I want to encrypt my SQS Queue for this I am using one of existing CMK "services-cmk". After queue is encrypted S3 is not able to invoke SQS. When I am putting message directly in encrypted SQS its working and lambda also got triggered.

I checked policy of services-cmk and it allows S3.I am not able to find out what I am missing here ?

Comment: What is the CMK policy?

Comment: @Marcin CMK policy allows action "kms:*" for principal "AWS" : "arn:aws:iam::account-id:root" and resource is also *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **explicitly specify S3** (using `root` as `Principal` is not enough) in your KMS key policy as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "example-ID",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "example-statement-ID",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```